# How to hide link from webview if internet is not available? Kotlin, Android studio

Tags: android

I want to hide webview link if the device is not connected to internet. I am using kotlin and android syudio. I am a beginner in android development.
My kotlin file is

```
val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.ftphnc_url)
    myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView?,
            url: String?
        ): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }
    }
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://10.16.100.244/")
    myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    myWebView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
    myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    myWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
    myWebView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to check for network connectivity and then use it in displaying.

```
fun Context.isConnectedToNetwork(): Boolean {
  val connectivityManager = this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
  return connectivityManager?.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnectedOrConnecting() ?: false
}
```

Then use the function with an `if` statment to display or not

```
if (context.isConnectedToNetwork()) {
  // Show the webview link
} else {
  // dont show webview link
}
```

Official docs: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type